# Google Data Studio send API request

Tags: looker-studio

I have my own community connector built which is pulling data through API. Everything works as it should, as I am getting data into the report.

Now I want to be able to query the API from the report, using a dedicated field/filter. What I mean is having the option to write a string and request API for results including that string.
What I have done so far is I've used the `request.configParams.field_name` parameter to pass request data from Google Data Studio back to my data source but this means reloading the data source into the report every time I change the value.

Is there another way to pass custom request data from Google Data Studio to my connector API query?

Answer (score 1):

For Community Connectors, it is not possible to push down arbitrary filters for report viewers at the moment (other than date filters).